# Unclear wording about declaration in template-declaration

Tags: c++, templates

`14/1 [temp]` provides:

> The declaration in a template-declaration shall
>
> (1.1) — declare or define a function, a class, or a variable, or
>
> (1.2) — define a member function, a member class, a member
>   enumeration, or a static data member of a class template or of a class
>   nested within a class template, or
>
> (1.3) — define a member template of a class or class template, or
>
> (1.4) — be an alias-declaration.

The second bullet is unclear because it looks as we cannot declare and not define a member of class template. But actually we can do that:

```
template <class U>
struct A
{
    template<class T>
    void foo();
};

int main(){}
```

[**CLANG**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42a17c809f9bebd5)

[**G++**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96a582edc655961b)

And that compiles fine by both clang and gcc. Could oyu explain what that means?

Comment: In `template<class T> void my_class<T>::mf() {}`, is `void my_class<T>::mf() {}` already the definition of a member function in that section? That may sound weird, but `T` is a new element in that declaration (the specification of what a *template-parameter* is follows in 14.1), that is not covered by the normal declaration rules AFAIK. OTOH, `void foo()` is an "ordinary" function declaration, even if it occurs inside a class, so I think your example is covered by 1.1

Comment: @dyp Forward references are not uncommon in the standard.

Comment: @Columbo Might 1.2 refer to `template<class T> template<class U> void A<T>::B<U>::foo() {}`, where the part `template<class U> void A<T>::B<T>::foo() {}` is *not* a function-definition but a template-declaration (so 1.1 doesn't apply)? That template-declaration does *not* define a member-template, so 1.3 doesn't apply either.

Comment: @dyp Yeah, but then why does it say "of a class template or a class template nested within a class template"? Why not just the nested case, the former is still mentioned?

Comment: @Columbo It would (only) make sense if the class was itself nested 2 levels inside a class template, such that we get `template<class T> template<class U> void A<T>::B<U>::C::foo() {}`. I suppose it's really only an emphasis, as you say in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <class U>
struct A
{
    template<class T>
    void foo();
};
```

As you can see, the *declaration* is `void foo();` which is a valid function declaration. Thus the first bullet point applies:

> The *declaration* in a *template-declaration* shall
>
> - declare or define a function, a class, or a variable, or
> - define a member function, a member class, a member enumeration, or a static data member of a class template or of a class nested within a
>     class template, or

Member functions are mentioned in the second bullet solely to underline that

```
template<class T>
void A<T>::foo() {}
```

is valid; The *declaration* in this *template-declaration* (`void A<T>::foo() {}`) is a member function definition. The "or" is not exclusive because the above *declaration* is still a function definition.

It now becomes clear that this can only concern definitions, since

```
template<class T>
void A<T>::foo();
```

isn't valid anyway.

Comment: Thank you, it clarifies the behavior.